# What is the best practice for validating form in rails with mongoDB and Backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mongodb, backbone.js

Hi I'm a new beginner in those three things.. 
I'm trying to use rails as many as possible and use backbone for ajax sending or events handling which rails cannot handle.

Now I'm trying to validate a form before saving in the Database.
I saw some validation practice which use Active record or Jquery validation.
Since I using mongodb I think I cannot use Active Record. and Jquery validation is a little bit slow and inconvenient for me so I just want to use backbone only right now for script language..

So My question is What is the best practice for validating form in rails with mongoDB and Backbone. Thank you

Comment: I don't know that there is a best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the client side I think you should take a look at backbone validation
https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation